# Error: read ECONNRESET at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27) Uploading the files to store i S3

Tags: storage, multer, multer-s3

When i am trying to upload the file and store in to s3 location, I got the error

```bash
    Error: read ECONNRESET
        at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
```

is the above a version problem or bug?

```js
    var express = require('express'), 
        aws = require('aws-sdk'),
        bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
        multer = require('multer'),
        multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
    
    aws.config.update({
        secretAccessKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        accessKeyId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        region: 'us-east-1'
    });
    
    var app = express(),
        s3 = new aws.S3();
    
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
    var upload = multer({
        storage: multerS3({
            s3: s3,
            bucket: 'xxxxx',
            key: function (req, file, cb) {
                console.log(file);
                cb(null, file.originalname); //use Date.now() for unique file keys
            }
        })
    });
    
    //open in browser to see upload form
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });
    
    //used by upload form
    app.post('/upload', upload.array('upl',1), function (req, res, next) {
        res.send("Uploaded!");
    });
    
    app.listen(3000, function () {
        console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
    });
```

and index html file

```html
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">
            <input type="file" name="upl"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

and packages version

```js
      "dependencies": {
        "aws-sdk": "^2.753.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "multer": "^1.4.2",
        "multer-s3": "^2.9.0"
      }
```

and my node and npm  versionn is

node is :12.16.1
npm is: 6.13.4

Please  any one solve this problem...

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this issue and after doing lots of analysis, I found that it is happening because of Antivirus installed on my machine. Particularly due to Sophos.
You can find this issue at - `https://community.sophos.com/intercept-x-endpoint/f/discussions/134136/sophos-network-threat-detection-is-blocking-cypress-automation-tool`

To solve this issue, try to execute your test cases on Electron browser, or contact your admin team and get the password of Sophos and then `Login into the Sophos, Go to settings and disable 'Network Threat Protection`

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be related to [this bug in NodeJS](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27916). One thing you can try is putting `res.end();` after your `res.sendFile(...)` and `res.send(...)` calls. If that doesn't work, you may need to implement a function to call on a process uncaughtException, or wait to see how the Node community ends up working around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using Node 16.7.0:

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:220:20) {
  errno: -54,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

I was able to solve it by adding `req.end()` after checking for the 'error' event.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to run 'npm install' in an Angular project using the node version 16.13.2.

When I switched the node version to 12.18.1 I was able to run the command with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Dont you have a crazy docker instance that is crashing and restarting on a loop ? Sometime it make cause random connection reset.

Answer (score 0):

#Error: read ECONNRESET

I had this issue in my Nextjs app, the solution was to `update node to LTS 18.x.x and node version to 9.9`